# How to upload Image and tweet the message without using TweetPic for twitter?

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, android-twitter

In my application i am using tweetPic to uploaded image but with the image is only able to see on the tweetPic. 
Instead of that i want to upload the picture on the twitter and also with the custom message. So how it is possible?
Twitter OAuth is also required for that.

I want any demo or sample example app that done like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have search many but still not get the answer as i want.

Finally i use this to upload the photo on Twitter with the Custom Message:

```
File picture = new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/"+filename+".jpg");  
   // Create TwitPic object and allocate TwitPicResponse object 
   TwitPic tpRequest = new TwitPic(TWITTER_NAME, TWITTER_PASSWORD); 
   TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;  
   // Make request and handle exceptions                            
   try {         
     tpResponse = tpRequest.uploadAndPost(picture, customMessageEditText.getText()+" http://www.MySite.com/");

   } 
   catch (IOException e) {         
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
   catch (TwitPicException e) {         
   e.printStackTrace(); 
   }  
   // If we got a response back, print out response variables                               
   if(tpResponse != null) {         
      tpResponse.dumpVars();
      System.out.println(tpResponse.getStatus());
      if(tpResponse.getStatus().equals("ok")){

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo posted on Twitter.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
 }
```

Still in search of the Twitter Demo to tweet pics on the Twitter with custom message with twitter OAuth and Without using twitPic.

Enjoy. :)

Thanks.

Comment: i had use the same But it shows me the message  INVALID USERNAME & PASSWARD even it is correct.

Comment: @Amandeepsingh: Well it works in my case but Let update the Answer. . .

Comment: @Amandeepsingh: please check the updated answer. It works in every case.